# Recurrence Relation of Compound Interest

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, finance

#### So I have the following question:

Suppose that at the end of some month (referred to as month 0), you open a
investment account with an initial investment of *I* dollars for some given *I* .The account grows at a fixed interest rate of *r%* per month, for a given *r* (note that if the quoted interest rate is an annual interest, then *r = r/12*). Suppose that at the end of every month you add some fixed amount *m* dollars for some given *m*. Denote *x<sub>n</sub>* by the amount of money you have in your account at the end of
month *n*.

a) Write a recurrence relation that relates *x<sub>n</sub>* to *x<sub>n-1</sub>*, for *n$\ge$t*. The relation should involve and *m,r,I,n*. Make sure to also indicate the value of *x<sub>0</sub>.*

b) Solve the recurrence relation of part (a).

c) Assume that *I* = \$10,000, *r* = 0.5%, and *m* = $1,000. Use part (b) to compute the value of the investment after 20 years

#### I derived the recurrence relation for part (a) as:

*x<sub>n</sub>* = (1+*r*)*x<sub>n-1</sub>* + m      *x<sub>0</sub>* = *I*

#### Then I used the following definition of a linear recurrence relation to solve for part (b)

*x<sub>n</sub>* =  ***a***  *x<sub>n-1</sub>* + ***b***  ==>  
*x<sub>n</sub>* =  *(x<sub>0</sub> - <sup>b</sup>⁄<sub>(1-a)</sub>
)*  *a<sup>n</sup>* - <sup>b</sup>⁄<sub>(1-a)</sub>

#### Where:

*a = (1+r)*   &    *b = m*

#### So:

*x<sub>n</sub>* = *(I - <sup>m</sup>⁄<sub>r</sub>) a<sup>n</sup>* - <sup>m</sup>⁄<sub>r</sub>

#### However, when I try to solve for part (c), I get a negative answer (and quite a large one at that).

Where my *n* = 12 months x 20 years = 240 months

#### So my assumption is that my initial equation is wrong, but I don't know what else it could be.  If anyone has a suggestion of what the proper equation is so I can solve it myself, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you must use is:
$$x_n=\left(x_0-\frac{b}{1-a}\right)\cdot a^n \color{red}{+} \frac{b}{1-a}.$$

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  I must've copied it down wrong in my notes